# Without loss of generality, a word describing a fixed amount of something

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I want a word that describes a fixed amount of matter which may or may not exist as part of a larger whole.

To be clear,

- An 'object' is a fixed amount of matter but implies discrete boundaries with other objects
- 'material' can exist discretely or as part of a whole, but it is ambiguous whether it is a fixed amount or a property

### A sample sentence:

Heat capacity is defined as the amount of energy required to raise the temperature of a (fixed quantity) of 'X' by 1 degree

Comment: The word "quantity", which you already have, seems to work perfectly in your sample sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use simpler words, you could do worse than:

#### amount

> the quantity at hand or under consideration
> ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amount))

is probably fine all by itself.  Note that ISO's standard quantity "[amount of substance](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/si-units-amount-substance)" seems to fit nicely with the usage you describe.

#### measure

> a measured quantity, AMOUNT, DEGREE
> ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/measure))

#### unit

> a determinate quantity adopted as a standard of measurement
> ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unit))

will work where the "unit" involved is defined.

---

A fun choice might be

#### scoop(ful)

> the amount contained by a scoop ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scoop))

Comment: @fertilizerspike There you go. I still prefer scooopful.

Comment: Scoopful is indeed whimsical and satisfies the conditions of the question IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can use **unit**. And you generally need to specify 'of what' the unit is. You can also use the chunky word "**chunk**".

**Chunk** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chunk))

> A representative portion of a substance.

You can also use some Latin derived terms.

**Monad** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monad))

> An ultimate atom, or simple, unextended point; something ultimate and
> indivisible.

**Quanta** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quanta))

> plural of quantum([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quantum#English): The total amount of something;
> quantity.  The amount or quantity observably present, or available.
> The smallest possible, and therefore indivisible, unit of a given
> quantity or quantifiable phenomenon.

**Quotum** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotum))

> A part or proportion; a fraction; quota.